# vba question. I am trying to filter one excel sheet based on a double click from another sheet. The code I am using doesnt seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

Here it is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 2 Then ' Check if double-click is in column 2 (B)
        Dim selectedItem As String
        selectedItem = Target.Value
        
        Dim wsPO As Worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wsPO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PODetail")
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not wsPO Is Nothing Then
            wsPO.Rows.Hidden = False ' Clear previous filter
            
            ' Column index for column 14 (N) in PODetails
            Dim columnIndex As Long
            columnIndex = 14
            
            wsPO.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=columnIndex, Criteria1:=selectedItem
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Nothing happens when I double click

Comment: Is the code in the worksheet code module for the worksheet you're double-clicking on?  Is `Application.EnableEvents` set to True?  Put a breakpoint in the event handler and see what happens as you step through.

Answer (score 0):

To reveal hidden rows after autofilter you have to use this

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
```

To switch off the arrows use

```vb
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: i updated the code but still when I double click in the field nothing happens

Comment: Did you replace ActiveSheet with the worksheet reference where your filter is  applied?